# Error while issuing db.collection.getShardDistribution() after removing a shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I had a 9-node cluster.  I removed one node.   When the task completed,  after I attempt to issue the command

```
mongos> db.collection.getShardDistribution()
```

I get the list of the 8 remaining shards but then an error message is shown at the end:

```
2014-11-12T13:11:23.965-0500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'host' of null at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1299
```

The only thing that comes to mind is I had an index on the 'host' field,  is it possible it wasn't cleanly removed somehow from the system...?

I can continue to search the collection with the .find() method,   but how do suppress this error/why is it being displayed at all?

Comment: This error precludes me from seeing the % distribution on all the shards.  I believe this is potentially a bug with MongoDB...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to get past this issue by restarting the mongos server:

```
$ mongos --configdb host0:27019 --port 27017
```

After restarting it and reconnecting to mongos,  i was able to issue:

```
mongos> db.collection.getShardDistribution()
```

and the problem went away.   I still think it's a bug but I guess if I can get past it by restarting it's not a big deal...